# How to use __func = None in Python decorators

Tags: python, decorator

I have the following decorator(as per https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/#decorators-with-arguments):

```
def slow_down(_func=None, rate = 1):

    def decorator(func):

        print(_func) # Added for understanding? 

        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            time.sleep(rate)
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper    


    if _func==None:
        return decorator

    else: return decorator(_func)
```

My question is, shouldn't a this `slow_down` function initialize with `_func = None` ? However, when I create a function with the decorator, I get an initialized _func value:

```
@slow_down
def countdown(time = 5):
    print(time)
    if time == 0: pass
    else: countdown(time-1)
<function countdown at 0x7f1aa0a8da60>
```

But when I initialize the value of the function, I get `None`:

```
@slow_down(rate=2)
def countdown(time = 5):
    print(time)
    if time == 0: pass
    else: countdown(time-1)

None
```

Shouldn't it be the other way around?

Comment: When you use a bare name for a decorator (as in `@slow_down`), it is called with the function being decorated as a parameter.  When parentheses are involved (as in the second case), the decorator is called as written, and is expected to return another function which gets called with the function being decorated as a parameter.  The `if` in your particular decorator allows it to work either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a bare name for a decorator (as in @slow_down), it is called with the function being decorated as a parameter. When parentheses are involved (as in the second case), the decorator is called as written, and is expected to return another function which gets called with the function being decorated as a parameter. The if in your particular decorator allows it to work either way. – jasonharper